# Ignore I/o count when syntheis and implementation on vivado

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vivado

I have a design that contains a lot of io  so they are more than the io of the fbga 
My design will be connected to a top level module 
But for now I want to syntheis that without connecting the design IOs to fbga bins

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I want the input out signals not to be connected to the fbga bins in the synthesis

Comment: The design is a cpu core it has a lot of io signals 
So it's more than the fbga can hold 
The module will be connected to another module later but for now I want to synthesis it to test the timing and so on 
But I cannot because it has too many inputs more than the fbga has

Comment: @Oldfart so do you have an answer

Comment: @Oldfart so do u have an answer

Comment: "But I cannot because it has too many inputs more than the fbga has" Where does that come from? Have you tried?

Comment: How about creating a wrapper module around your CPU with only selected IOs?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is [out-of-context](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2013_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) mode. That allows you to synthesize a module with all the IO as virtual pins.

You can set it through the GUI as described on page 20 here: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2013_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf

Or using the TCL command:

```
set_property -name {STEPS.SYNTH_DESIGN.ARGS.MORE OPTIONS} -value {-mode out_of_context} -objects [get_runs synth_1]
```